# How to Edit .Aspx Files?

Tags: html, asp.net, image, backend

I am trying to edit the following page: http://tktruck.com/contact.aspx in order to get rid of the cat photos.

Apparently there is no contact.aspx file in the FTP, so I am having trouble figuring out how to edit this page's content.

Some additional information:

I have access to the back-end (FTP files). I have searched the FTP for contact.aspx, and I cannot find the file. I have tried searching the entire website for  tags with the appropriate sources, as well. I found some code with the image tags, and removed those tags. When I uploaded the code to the server, the images were still there (and still are).

Does anyone know what I have to do to edit an aspx file, or at least have an idea on how to remove these photos?

Comment: This all depends on the development/production environment. In professional development, you _never_ edit pages on the web server. You edit them in some source control system, test them, then deploy them to the site. How would you edit a .php file?

Comment: I have a local copy of the website on my desktop. So I have 2 versions of the website. I have deployed my changes, and nothing is happening. Perhaps, there is a specific file or code I have to change to allow these edits to go through? I'm not even sure why there is no contact.aspx file in the system, yet in the URL it contains `contact.aspx`. Well, normally with PHP, there would be a contact.php file I would be able to edit. Here, there is no contact.aspx file!

Comment: Again, you need to get help from people who have worked with this site before. There's no magic about editing .aspx files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get access to the server in which the website is hosted.

Comment: I have access to the back-end (FTP files). I have searched the FTP for contact.aspx, and I cannot find the file. I have tried searching the entire website for <img> tags with the appropriate sources, as well. I found some code with the image tags, and removed those tags. When I uploaded the code to the server, the images were still there (and still are)..

Comment: @Kelsey: maybe you should ask the people who created the site? Because it sounds like you shouldn't be editing live pages at this stage in your learning process.

Comment: Im with @JohnSaunders - something doesn't sound right here. You need access to either source or where the website is being hosted via IIS. Plain and simple.

Comment: Here is the cat photo. I would keep it.. http://tktruck.com//media/27428/troy-cat.jpg

Comment: What source? I have access to all of the web files via FTP.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a 3rd party host and can access and update the files via FTP. If that is the case, your FTP folder is mapped to your web root. From there you should see your aspx file. But this is a bad way to handle this. As @JohnSaunders said, you should have a source and then publish.

Comment: So, you are saying I should find my aspx file (contact.aspx) in my web root?